# Eigenvalue For A 2-Fold Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products

This is problem 4 from page 258 of *Curtis's Linear Algebra: An Introductory Approach*.  I seem to be having trouble understanding something needed to solve the problem, which reads

> Suppose **A** and **B** are matrices in triangular form, with zeros
>   above the diagonal.  Show that **A** $\times$ **B** has the same
>   property, and hence that every eigenvalue of **A** $\times$ **B** can
>   be expressed in the form $\alpha\beta$, where $\alpha$ is an
>   eigenvalue on **A** and $\beta$ is an eigenvalue of **B**.

In the actual problem, there's a little dot above the cross in the "matrix product" **A** $\times$ **B** to signify that the resulting matrix represents a transformation on the vector space of tensors $V \otimes W$.  Because this matrix has entries given by

$$\pmatrix{
\alpha_{11}\mathbf{B} & \alpha_{12}\mathbf{B} & ... & \alpha_{1n}\mathbf{B} \\
... \\
\alpha_{n1}\mathbf{B} & \alpha_{n2}\mathbf{B} & ... & \alpha_{nn}\mathbf{B}
}$$

when represented against the basis $\lbrace v_1 \otimes w_1 , ... , v_1 \otimes w_m , v_2 \otimes w_1 , ... , v_2 \otimes w_m , ... , v_n \otimes w_m \rbrace$, I can understand the first claim in the problem (i.e. that the matrix **A** $\times$ **B** is also triangular).  I'm having trouble proving that every eigenvector of the above matrix can be represented as a product of eigenvectors of **A** and **B**.

Because of how linear transformations on tensor products are defined, we know that

$$
(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b}) = (\mathbf{Aa} \otimes \mathbf{Bb})
$$

Also, if $\gamma$ is an eigenvalue of **A** $\times$ **B**, then

$$
(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b}) = \gamma (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b}).
$$

But at this point, I'm stuck...

Comment: The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are its diagonal entries.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Would you be able to post your comment as an answer?  Then I can mark it as a solution to the problem.  I realize I got tripped up on something really minor, but you did figure out where I got stuck:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are its diagonal values.

You can prove this by computing the characteristic polynomial, but you can also without too much effort write down the eigenvectors inductively.